# Ion-native Google map is not free, why it requires Api key?

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic-native, google-geocoding-api

I am using Ionic-native Geo-location for getting lat and lng but when i run the code i get to know that its for "development purpose only".

i have tried v3 or others without api key.

home.html

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map_center">
      <img src="../../assets/icon/marker.png" />
    </div>
    <div #map id="map"></div>
  </div>
```

I expected google maps without api key because i am using ionic native plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that google maps requires a API key now is because Google changed the pricing plan for Google Maps. You are now required to create a cloud account and activate the Maps API. 
For more details see: [Google Maps docs](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?hl=nl).

This has nothing to do with the ionic-native plugin.

Comment: you are right.. but i have to buy it? if i want to use it for long term? even if i am trying it for 30 days trail, it shows me development purpose message

Comment: Yes you'll need to consult with a google sales rep. if you want to utilise the api. The development message is there to remind you of the fact that the API is not suitable for production environment.